# C# Winforms - Display Tooltip over textbox when mouse not over it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, textbox, visual-studio-2017

I am working on a project in Visual Studio 2017, using Winforms and C#. I have created a textbox which accepts only certain characters, and I would like it to display a bubble tooltip saying "Only letters and numbers are allowed" whenever a user enters an invalid character. I have managed to display a tooltip:

```
//titleInput - The textbox.
//characterWarning - the tooltip.

private void TitleInputKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) && !Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) && !Char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar) && !Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)) //Check if character is invalid.
    {
        characterWarning.SetToolTip(titleInput, "Only letters and numbers are allowed"); //Display the tooltip.
        e.Handled = true; //
    }
}
```

But it is shown only if the mouse is over the textbox, and if the textbox is in focus. **How do I make a tooltip show over a textbox even if the mouse is not over the control?** Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tooltip control on the form, you can do it like this:

```
ToolTip1.Show("Text to display", Control)
```

Check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.show.aspx) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip.Show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip.show?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads) Method instead.